# JS: Received Parameter from a function is differ than actual parameter

Tags: javascript

I am facing an weird situation. I am sending a parameter to the method. On receiving end I got different parameter.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

**JS Code:**

```
    <script>
var defaultOptions = {
    chart:{
        "type":"series",
        "container":"#container",
        "width":700,
        "height":500,
        "margin":{
            "left":100 , top:50 , right:10 , "bottom":50
        }
    }

};



var Util = {
    /**
     *@return true if the given object is an valid one.
     */
    valid: function(obj){
        return obj !== undefined && obj !== null;
    },
    /**
     *@param a {object} to extend.
     *@param b {object} 
     *@return {object}
     */
    extend:function(a , b){
        var m;
        if(!Util.valid(a)){
            a = {};
        }
        for(m in b){
            a[m] = b[m];
        }
        return a;
    }

};


function Chart(opt){
    console.log(opt);
    /**
     *Setting default chart options.
     */
    Util.extend(opt , defaultOptions);


}


var ChartLite = {}; 

Util.extend(ChartLite , {
    Chart:Chart
});
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
    var chart = new ChartLite.Chart({});
});
</script>
```

JS Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/993Wu/15/

**Sending** : {}.

**Expected** : {}

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Where in the code is the received value being printed?

Comment: @Barmar , function Chart(opt){
    console.log(opt);

in Chart method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the output of the `console` shows you the status of the object *as it is now*, not *as it was when you called `console.log`*.

The best way to get the *current* status of an object is to `JSON.stringify()` it before you output it; note that this will remove all functions and non-JSON properties.

Comment: I wasted 30 minutes on that. I printed before calling `extend` method. Thanks a lot.